# Changing Material UI Chip primary or secondary color

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to programmatically change the color of a Material UI `Chip` without much luck. According to the [`Chip` API](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/chip/) you have to set the color via the color prop with one of three values from an enum; default, primary, and secondary. You should then be able to override the the `colorPrimary` or `colorSecondary` css classes and the background color should change.

Here is an example of my code:

```js
<Chip key={label.id} color='primary' classes={{ colorPrimary: label.color }} label={label.label} />
```

And a picture of the element in browser:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/P0IPA.png cant inline yet :(

If you look at the selected element, you will see the correct color I am trying to apply, #ff0000, so it is getting the color and putting it somewhere.

I've tried this variation, adding the colorBackground property, but I get an error saying the colorPrimary class expects a string instead of an object

```js
<Chip key={label.id} color='primary' classes={{ colorPrimary: { backgroundColor: label.color } }} label={label.label} />
```

Again to reiterate my goal: I want to apply a hex code color to the chip to change the background color.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

you can make it in many ways.

you can add styles directly

```
<Chip key={label.id} color='primary' style={{backgroundColor:'green'}} label={label.label} />
```

or you can override the class:

```
const StyleChip = withStyles({
  root: {
    backgroundColor:'salmon'
  }
})(Chip);
```

to use everywhere you only will replace `Chip` to `StyleChip`

```
<StyleChip key={label.id} color='primary' label={label.label} />
```

but if you wanna put the color by programation, the first way is perfect, because

`style={{backgroundColor:_thisCanBeVariable_}}`

Comment: Much appreciated, I tried using the styles prop but I am not sure I used the right class name, I think I was trying colorPrimary to override the color prop. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

You can set the `primary` or `secondary` color of the `Chip` component easily using `createTheme`:

```
const theme = createTheme({
  components: {
    MuiChip: {
      styleOverrides: {
        colorPrimary: {
          backgroundColor: 'red',
        },
        colorSecondary: {
          backgroundColor: 'brown',
        },
      },
    },
  },
});
```

```
<Chip label="primary" color="primary" />
<Chip label="secondary" color="secondary" />
```

Or if you're using **MUI v5**, you can quickly change its color with the help of `sx` prop:

```
<Chip label="sx" sx={{ bgcolor: 'green', color: 'white' }} />
```

If you want to be able to specify different color via a prop, you can use `styled`:

```
const options = {
  shouldForwardProp: (prop) => prop !== 'bgcolor',
};
const StyledChip = styled(
  Chip,
  options,
)(({ bgcolor }) => ({
  color: 'white',
  backgroundColor: bgcolor,
}));
```

```
<StyledChip label="styled" bgcolor="purple" />
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Answer (score 4):

For those trying to get this previous to the v5 (which would need to add a new color to the palette) a simple wrapper will get the job done:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import MaterialChip from '@material-ui/core/Chip';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const Chip = (props) => {
    const StyledChip = withStyles({
        root: {
            'color': 'white',
            'backgroundColor': `${props.color} !important`,
            '&:hover': {
                backgroundColor: props.color,
                filter: 'brightness(120%)',
            },
            '&:active': {
                boxShadow: 'none',
                backgroundColor: props.color,
                borderColor: props.color,
            },
        },
        outlined: {
            color: props.color,
            border: `1px solid ${props.color}`,
            backgroundColor: `transparent !important`,
        },
        icon: {
            color: props.variant === 'outlined' ? props.color : 'white',
        },
        deleteIcon: {
            color: props.variant === 'outlined' ? props.color : 'white',
        },
    })(MaterialChip);

    return <StyledChip {...props} />;
};

Chip.propTypes = {
    color: PropTypes.string,
    variant: PropTypes.oneOf(['regular, outlined']),
};

export default Chip;
```